# Animation not working on iPad. same works on iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, animation

I've got a very simple project that tries to animate a UIView using block based iOS4.0 animation.

header

```
@interface animatepadViewController : UIViewController {

    UIView *contentView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;



@end
```

implementation

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{self.contentView.alpha = 0.0;}];

}
```

I've added a subview of type UIVIew in the interface builder with a background color of black.

these are the only change i've made from the default ipad "view" based project.

I get the following error

```
2010-12-28 17:59:05.689 animatepad[29835:207] *** +[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x217689c
```

this happens only on the ipad and NOT on the iPhone

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the simulator, you will need to update Xcode to version 3.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your iPad to use iOS 4.2 yet? Blocks weren't available on the iPad's shipping version of iOS (3.2.)

Comment: ahh.. thats probably it. how do i do that for the simulator ?