# ios UIView animation using blocks issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to convert old styled animation to blocks using style. The following code work fine:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeAndMove" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
selected_view.frame = targetSlot.frame;
selected_view.center = targetSlot.center;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But this converted wont work:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3f
     animations:^{
         selected_view.frame = targetSlot.frame;
         selected_view.center = targetSlot.center;
     }
 ];
```

It says:

```
 2012-10-17 12:32:50.256 myapp[311:207] *** +[UIView
 animateWithDuration:animations:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
 0x21b989c 2012-10-17 12:32:50.259 myapp[311:207] *** Terminating app
 due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
 +[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x21b989c'
```

I'm using ios 4.1 with iPad simulator. It compiles ok but always crashes. Can't figure out whats wrong. Even simple example from apple dev:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

works the same way - it just crashes with the same message (with only "completion:" adding).
Whats wrong with argument? Which argument at all? Do I need to import something to add support of blocks? But it compiles fine...
I can even see in the UIKit/UIView:

```
...
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0); // delay = 0.0, options = 0, completion = NULL
...
```

Comment: Can you double-check the version of the simulator?

Comment: seems you need remove xcode and install latest xcode again.

Comment: iOS Deployment target = iOS 4.1, Base SDK = iOS simulator 4.1, running on iPad emu version 4.1 (225).

Comment: Did you clean your project and rebuild?

Comment: I did Clean/Clean all targets and even threw the "build" subfolder of my project to trash. no luck.

Comment: The Settings app in the simulator really says "iOS 4.1" ? Do you have any other iOS 4+ API that work?

Comment: By the way, do you happen to be using Mountain Lion?  I've heard reports that the 4.x simulator on Mountain Lion is terribly buggy (so much so that it was removed by Apple)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animation not working on iPad. same works on iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546069/animation-not-working-on-ipad-same-works-on-iphone)

Comment: Eventually when I'd added ASIHTTP lib it started to say that there is no _UIBlahBlahBackground (or something like) symbol was found in Iphone simulator 3.2! Why does it use 3.2 I have no glue. But if I switch my app from iPad to IPhone with min. iOS4.1 it starts to work fine, no crashes. Switching back to iPad makes it use iOS3.2. Installing a newer version of XCode resolved all of issues (and added some new i'm afraid :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently upgraded to xcode 4.5 as this no longer will support ios 4.1.

The only other thing I can think of is the variables you're using are not safe to use in blocks. To make them safe simply add __block when initialising the variable. Does seem a strange one!

Comment: Im using an older xcode version which has 4.1 support. Also I tried to use apple_dev's example with self.view and anyway block should see my vars due to same scope.

Comment: where are you using this method? As in ViewDidAppear or a custom method or a button selector?

Comment: Also are you using a nib or loading views programatically

Comment: I'm using nib and this method used in touchesEnded but does it really matter in my case?

Answer (score 0):

NSTimeInterval is not a float.  Its a double. Which is why your original code worked.

Comment: Nonsense, his original code was integer anyway.  The compiler will implicitly convert it to the correct type.  It certainly won't be a runtime error.

Comment: and his original code was not an integer it was an untyped primitive which is not the same as specifying the exact type with .3f - thats explicit not a cast.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I remember reading that the default is an int for a literal with no decimal places.  Regardless, if it were not the correct type that would be a compiler error.  This is a runtime error.

Comment: I dont know Im too lazy to compile it - but a double is not a float.  And NStimeInterval is a double.  I dont see that as being a safe implicit conversion.  And why wouldnt the compiler flag an warning about the signature its NOT the signature.  With clang you cant even pass a typed int as a long so the message dispatch should not even find the method.

Comment: Well I know for a fact that float will work in it.  I've used it myself, the compiler will not flag it as suspicious even with suspicious implicit conversions enabled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18166/discussion-between-stackmonster-and-borrrden)

Comment: apple_dev's example is without any specified type for duration. So "animateWithDuration:0.2" can't be a problem I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Installing a newer version of XCode resolved the issue. Before installing my current version of XCode was removed using sudo.